# How to make left child take its full width using tailwind CSS or just CSS

Tags: html, css, image, next.js, tailwind-css

[image]I am having issue while making the left div take its full width. On left I have div and its child is `<Image/> from Next/Image`.

On the right I have another child with just text box. I want left image to come beneath the right text box and take its full width while right child stay where it is.[image]

I have added second image where behind the left side you can see the shadow. That is the image and on the right there is text box. So image shadow should be below behind the text-box.

Comment: can you send an approximate sketch of what you want it to look like . you can just use paint

Comment: Added another image. Image shadow is coming behind the  textBox on the right side .